# Can I find username login log in Active directory server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, log-files, forensics

I join computer into  active directory(AD) domian. User in  AD can login to computer by using username, password in AD. Computer was install deep freeze so it can not keep anything after restart. I want to find username login log. I search in AD server envent viewer -> security ,but it have no username login log. It only show admin username log which login to AD server only. Can I find username login log in Active directory server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable account logon auditing in your domain and use the security log to monitor the activity. This blog post provides the basic process and which event IDs you can expect to see after enabling the auditing: https://www.lepide.com/blog/audit-successful-logon-logoff-and-failed-logons-in-activedirectory/